# Add scripts dynamically in a page JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, appendchild

Following is my [PLNKR CODE](http://plnkr.co/edit/LiHSXafMP6XpcTVGmLDf?p=preview) for creating dynamic script elements. But it is throwing following error -

> TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.appendChild is not an object.
>
> document.head.appendChild("script1");

I also tried `document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]` for targeting but it again throw the same error.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong with the concept.

This is the answer I followed for this - [Stack Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12786867/1594368)

My `JS` code -

```
(function(){

  var script1 = document.createElement('script');
  script1.src= "script1.js";
  //document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild("script1");
  document.head.appendChild("script1");

  var add = document.createElement('script');
  add.src= "add.js";
  //document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild("add");
  document.head.appendChild("add");

  var subtract = document.createElement('script');
  subtract.src= "subtract.js";
  //document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild("subtract");
  document.head.appendChild("subtract");

  $("#add").find('.result').text(c);
  $("#subtract").find('.result').text(d);

})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are passing string instead of the element reference.

Do this:

```
document.head.appendChild(script1);
```

instead of:

```
document.head.appendChild("script1");
```

Comment: I changed but now I am getting error - ReferenceError: c is not defined, though if I run `$("#add").find('.result').text(c);` in the console it is populating a weird answer as 20, though I guess it should be 180

Comment: because the javascript compiler doesn't find any reference to variable "c". Are you setting this variable in one of the javascript dynamically loaded? try setting on window in your dynamic script e.g. window.c = "something"; Then access it using window.c